# Redirect in the same page doesnt work?

Tags: php, redirect

i have this code:

```
// index.php
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && !isset($_SESSION['id']){    
     // My Code 
     if($ris1['pass'] == $pass)){ // it controls if the pass the user inserts is true...
         $_SESSION['user'] = $ris1['user'];
         $_SESSION['id'] = $ris1['id'];
         die(header("Location: index.php")); // the same page 
     }
} else { 
     // My Code 
}
```

I insert : `die(header("Location: index.php"));` for redirect automatically the page, but it if the pass is correct, it saves my Session, but, when i redirect the user, the user sees half of the same page you see if the $_SESSION is not define but the $_SESSION is isset, and i for see what i have in the else (in my code) i must update the page... 
I try use ob_start() , but it doesn't work...
Why the my page doesn't redirect automatically and go , in the else?

Comment: Did you started session at the beginning of `index.php`?

Comment: Remember that according to the current version of the HTTP/1.1 standard, RFC 2616, the value of the Location header must be an absolute URI... Don't know if it's the solution to the problem, but take this into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redirect before aborting the current code :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) && !isset($_SESSION['id'])) {    
     // My Code 
     if($ris1['pass'] == $pass)){ // it controls if the pass the user inserts is true...
         $_SESSION['user'] = $ris1['user'];
         $_SESSION['id'] = $ris1['id'];
         header("Location: index.php"); // the same page 
         die();
     }
} else { 
     // My Code 
}
```